# Symfony2 best practices for stay DRY

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, coding-style, dry

I'm new to Symfony2. I have to learn it for my new job (it starts this monday). Before that, I used a lot CodeIgniter... so this change a bit.

After reading tons of documentations, tuts, best practices ... create my Own intranet for testing (customers has websites, websites has accesses, accesses has website, website has category, accesses has accesscategory) I still have some questions.

**First Question :**

When you have a website with frontend and backend you have all the time some repetitives actions like :
- create new entity
- read entity
- update entity
- delete entity
...

In CI, I create a BaseController and a BaseModel and with some extends, I was OK.

This practice is still OK for Symfony 2 or do Symfony have another way to handle that ?

Like AppBundle\Controller\BaseController extended by a AppBundle\Controller\AdminController (and FrontController) extended by AppBundle\Controller\MyEntityController ?

Because Actually, each time, in each controller I have the same code. When I edit an entity (for example), it's the same process : load the entity by id, throw exception if no entity, create and hydrate the form, handleRequest the post and valid the form, reidrect or display the view... but... I always cut/paste the same code... aweful T__T

So I'm searching for the best way to handle that

** Second Question : **

What is the best and elegent way to work with the DoctrineManager ?

Do I have to call it, each time in my actions ? `$em = $this->get...` or, can I create something like MyEntityManager which call the EntityManager and the repository of my entity ?

Actually, this is what I do :

I create an abstract AppBundle\Manager\BaseManager with loadAndFlush

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Manager;

abstract class BaseManager
{
    protected function persistAndFlush($entity)
    {
        $this->em->persist($entity);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
```

}

Then, for each Entity, I create his own manager :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Manager;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use AppBundle\Manager\BaseManager;
use AppBundle\Entity\Customer;

class CustomerManager extends BaseManager
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    protected $em;

    /**
     * @param EntityManager $em
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * @param $customerId
     * @return null|object
     */
    public function loadCustomer($customerId)
    {
        return $this->getRepository()
            ->findOneBy(array('id' => $customerId));
    }

    /**
     * @param Customer $customer
     */
    public function saveCustomer(Customer $customer)
    {
        $this->persistAndFlush($customer);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
     */
    public function getRepository()
    {
        return $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Customer');
    }

}
```

Then, I define this manager as a service :

```
parameters:
    app.customer_manager.class: AppBundle\Manager\CustomerManager

services:
    app.customer_manager:
        class: %app.customer_manager.class%
        arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
```

And Then I use the service in my Controller :

```
/**
 * @Route("/edit/{customerId}", name="customer_edit")
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")
 */
public function editAction($customerId, Request $request)
{
    if (!$customer = $this->get('app.customer_manager')->loadCustomer($customerId)) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException($this->get('translator')->trans('This customer does not exist.'));
    }

    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(new CustomerType(), $customer);

    if($form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {

        $this->get('app.customer_manager')->saveCustomer($customer);

        $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Client bien enregistré.');

        return $this->redirect(
            $this->generateUrl(
                'customer_show', array(
                    'customerId' => $customer->getId()
                )
            )
        );
    }

    return $this->render('default/customer/add.html.twig', array(
        'form'      => $form->createView(),
        'customer'  => $customer
    ));

}
```

Is it a good practice, is it too complicated ? Is there any better other way to process in symfony ?

Comment: It's too broad question. Symfony2 allows you to implement almost any architecture. Some programmers prefer build MVC on top of it, some prefer using CRUD generators or bundles like SonataAdmin. I prefer DDD approach of building Symfony2 applications.

Answer (score 0):

For first question Symfony2 provides CRUD Generator, take a look at [**this**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_crud.html).

For second one you should use Repository Pattern provided by framework, for more information about this checkout following links:

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx
2. http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes

Comment: The problem with the crub generator... if you take 2 entities, you generate 2 cruds ... and you have exactly the same code... only the Entity changes...

I'm searching a way to dont have this repetition.

Same for repositories

Comment: you can simply abstract it and override entity property in sub classes.

Comment: also remember to make base views for BaseCrudController, how ever it's hard to go in details with making views. I prefer to use Symfony2 suggested structure.